# Creating a Dynamic form with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Lets start again,

I would like to loop through a few values and then append them to a form to show a select box,

This is my button to add a new field in HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Field" onclick="addField()">
```

Then the addField Javascript:

```
 function addField() {
 var input = document.createElement('input');
 input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
 input.setAttribute('name', "newDrop[]");
 input.setAttribute('id', 'newDrop');
 input.setAttribute('class', 'newDrop');
 input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Options');
 document.getElementById('dropdown').appendChild(input);
 };
```

As you can see that this will append a new form with the attributes above.
Once I am happy with the values in each field and submit the additional fields with the below HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Create Field"  onclick="addInput('dynamicInput')">
```

I am hoping to create a dynamically created select with the details I added in the fields.

What I would like to happen is that I can loop through the values and create the options with the values that have been entered in the fields.  My Javascript for this is below:

```
function addInput(divName) {
  //other case here
  case 'dropdown':
  myInputs[counter]['atts'] = [];
  myInputs[counter]['atts']['label']    =          document.getElementById('fieldDropDownLabel').value
  myInputs[counter]['atts']['one']  =      document.getElementsByName('newDrop[]')
  break;
  }
  var dd = document.createElement('select');
  //other cases go here
  case 'dropdown':
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  label.textContent = myInputs[counter]['atts']['label'];
  label.setAttribute('for', myInputs[counter]['atts']['label']);
  label.setAttribute('id', 'dropdown');
  f.appendChild(label);
  dd.setAttribute('name', myInputs[counter]['atts']['label'])
  //default option
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = 'Please Select';
  option.value = '';
  dd.add(option, dd.options[null]);
  //additional options
  var option1 = document.createElement('option')
  var newDrop = myInputs[counter]['atts']['one']
  for(i=0; i < newDrop.length; i++)
  {
    option1.text = myInputs[counter]['atts']['one'];
    option1.value = myInputs[counter]['atts']['one'];
    dd.add(option1, dd.options[null]);
  }
  counter++;
  f.appendChild(dd);
    break;
```

I am just unable to get the values to show in the select options.  Hopefully this is better than the last post.. Is there any chance someone can help?

Thanks

Comment: No one wants to sift through your entire code base. You should extract the relevant bits (or contrive a new example) and put them directly in this question

Comment: Thanks for help, I have added the code that I think that is needed.  I am new to javascript so I may have missed something off.

Comment: You should probably start with a smaller example, for example, adding just two types of inputs. As it is, I have a feeling you have a few terms mixed up, and it makes it hard to understand what you want.

Comment: I have changed my example and I was wondering if this now makes sense?